# PHP script to run python3 .py file

Tags: python, php

I'm trying to run a python file from a PHP script. The intended thing to happen is that when one browses to the */webhookMac.php on my site, the script name MacLabLogin.py will run. For some reason though, nothing happens. I checked the logs on my Apache2 server but I see no related logs (all the logs are from months ago).

Here is my PHP code

```
<?php
$command = escapeshellcmd("python3 /location/of/file/from/root/MacLabLogin.py");
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;
?>
```

PHP works on my webserver and I know that PHP file is accessible and runs but for some reason, the part of running the .py file doesn't run the file. The python script also works when I run it manually.

PS: 
The "echos" don't return anything. The webpage is blank. 
I am on an Amazon Linux EC2 Instance.

Comment: Perhaps your `www-data` user doesn't have python3 in it's path? Or it cannot execute python?

Comment: If the precise return value of shell_exec is null it is likely there was some error. Can you try with `exec()` and see if you can grab the return code?

Comment: So I added exec() and I don't get any errors but my final print() statement in my python script shows what it's supposed to print (I have other print() statements but the final print statement is there to test if the code worked and it says it did so I'm not too concerned the others got skipped.) However, I executed this manually doing "php webhookMac" so I wonder why it's just the site then.

Annoying enough. I can only fully test this once per day so I'll have to see tomorrow if it actually works. In the meantime, I'll investigate added python as a PATH to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the issue was that the selenium module could not be found. I added the selenium module files in the same file of the script and it was able to run smoothly.

`pip3 install selenium -t /path/to/root/of/.py/script/`